# HTML / CSS : float left not working correctly, div showing up below previous div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a 2 column layout using class="left" and class="right", at the moment my .right column will not float left and is showing up below my .left column.

When I remove everything inside .left and .right the float works correctly, can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why do you call it `right` and float it `left`???

Comment: Please trim your code down to a minimum example that still shows the behavior.

Comment: ...and for the record, the problem is probably not that float is not working correctly, but that your understanding of how they work is not correct. Big difference.

Comment: I thought if I floated it left it would just be placed next to the last div, which would be the right side column. Is this not done correctly?

Comment: can you show only the code where you're having the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `right` div is inside your `left` div. You have a comment that says `</div><!-- left -->` but it isn't actually the end of the left div. Look at it in an editor that support highlighting of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an unclosed `div` in your `.left` code.

Adding another end `div` tag to the end of that block seems to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/SG8sE/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you have padding and/or margins defined on the .left and .right divs, make sure there is room for each of them (with content) to appear side by side.

I find it helpful to put a 1px border around elements while working on an initial layout to really get a handle on where everything is.